# Failed cvxpy instllation -> failed building qdldl wheel -> ... -> zsh: command not found: xcode-select

Tags: python, zsh, apple-m1, python-wheel, cvxpy

I think I might scream. I'm on a Macbook Pro M1 Max 32 GB on Sonoma 14.0. Python 3.11.2 in Visual Studio.

I have been trying to pip install cvxpy for an assignment for my grad school optimization coursework. However, it always fails and says that it failed building the wheel for qdldl. Output pasted below.

```
Collecting cvxpy
  Using cached cvxpy-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl.metadata (8.8 kB)
Collecting osqp>=0.6.2 (from cvxpy)
  Using cached osqp-0.6.3.tar.gz (228 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [108 lines of output]
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.8.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
      Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
        Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting setuptools_scm>=6.2
        Using cached setuptools_scm-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
      Collecting qdldl
        Using cached qdldl-0.1.7.post0.tar.gz (70 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting numpy==1.21.6 (from oldest-supported-numpy)
        Using cached numpy-1.21.6-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (12.4 MB)
      Collecting packaging>=20 (from setuptools_scm>=6.2)
        Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting typing-extensions (from setuptools_scm>=6.2)
        Using cached typing_extensions-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
      Collecting tomli>=1 (from setuptools_scm>=6.2)
        Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=0.13.2 (from qdldl)
        Using cached scipy-1.11.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (112 kB)
      Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.8 kB)
      Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (807 kB)
      Using cached wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Using cached setuptools_scm-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
      Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
      Using cached scipy-1.11.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (29.8 MB)
      Using cached typing_extensions-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: qdldl
        Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [59 lines of output]
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_ext
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
                from cmake import cmake
            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
                main()
              File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
              File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
                return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
                return self._build_with_temp_dir(
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
                self.run_setup()
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
                exec(code, locals())
              File "<string>", line 113, in <module>
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
                return run_commands(dist)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
                self.run_command("build")
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
                self.run_command(cmd_name)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 88, in run
                _build_ext.run(self)
              File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-v1k57da4/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
                self.build_extensions()
              File "<string>", line 81, in build_extensions
              File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
                return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
              File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
                raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
            subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for qdldl
      Failed to build qdldl
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for qdldl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Okay. So I follow that rabbit path to try to fix qdldl. Here's the output when I try to pip install qdldl.

```
Collecting qdldl
  Using cached qdldl-0.1.7.post0.tar.gz (70 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from qdldl) (1.26.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.2 in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from qdldl) (1.10.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: qdldl
  Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [59 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 113, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/f1/s2qr53sd25n7q8ps1n__4zxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-90im7uk2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "<string>", line 81, in build_extensions
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qdldl
Failed to build qdldl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for qdldl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

So, basically the same error as with cvxpy. Aright. I do some reading online about the problem. I download the qdldl zip from github to try installing it that way, but when I cd to where the qdldl folder is, cmake also fails.

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

The hell is this. I try uninstalling and reinstalling cmake, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode and its accompanying CLT. No joy. Between SO and Apple Dev, I try to get Xcode working with the terminal, but now I cannot even get the zsh shell to install Xcode because I get `zsh: command not found: xcode-select`.

I have also tried via Homebrew and get the `No available formula with the name` / `No formulae or casks found`. I have updated pip and its dependencies. I have tried basically everything I've been able to find on here relating to these specific issues but no luck.

I think I'm going to scream. Does anyone know why I'm having such a f$%&ing hard time with this? I've been able to install other packages up till now without this issue and idk what to do anymore. Honestly, while my laptop has a good amount of beefiness, I have had one woe after another when it comes to my terminal and trying to figure out what the hell is up with stuff like this (I previously tried getting TensorFlow to work and got snared in a similarly convoluted chicken-and-egg problem). Doesn't help that it's now a zsh shell, either.

Is there a comparable package I could try using otherwise? My instructor showed us some code and told us we needed to use cvxpy so I'm royally screwed if I can't figure out how to get this to work....

Stuff I've tried: updating pip and setuptools. Uninstalling and reinstalling cmake. Failed installing qdldl directly. Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode and CLT, cannot get the terminal to talk to them. Trying through Homebrew. Going through every Stack Overflow and Apple Dev post possible that's related, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920955/failed-building-wheel-for-qdldl-when-installing-cvxpy).

Comment: Is your `$PATH` broken? Do you not have `/usr/bin/xcode-select`?

Comment: @Siguza That's my fear. I think I'll need to either factory reset or figure out how to reset my terminal to start all over again. I got the M1 right when it came out so Lord knows how much junk has accumulated since I've had so many failed or messed up installs trying to get stuff to work with the M1 chip.